# Georeferencing an image to a Progressive JPEG

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, georeferencing, image

I am using the Georeferencing tool in ArcGIS 10.2 to georeference a normal JPEG image. 
I want to produce a georeferenced Progressive JPEG image from that image, but there is no JPEG Progressive option in the Rectify window dialog:

[image]

It seems ArcGIS has the capabilities to produce Progressive JPEG, just not through the georeferencing toolbar. Rather, it can produce a Progressive JPEG by exporting the map to an image through File - Export Map:

[image]

Exporting my georeferenced image to a Progressive JPEG through Export Map would be cumbersome and maybe cause loss of image quality.

Do you know any workaround to this?

Answer (score 1):

Export the image from Data View. Check the Write World file in the general tab.  There you can also control the image output resolution and size.  Image quality of the output will be compromised either way because you have georeferenced the image and thus altered/warped or stretched the original pixels. Work out the outptut size and resolution that closely matches the original or larger. Works fine IMO. [image]

Comment: + 1 but wouldn't the Export Map tool create a white margin around the JPEG image? It does on my side.

Comment: If you zoom out beyond the image extent then it likely will.  If the jpeg completely fills the data view window then it will not. After georeferencing, depending on what method you used, the original jpeg will be distorted and no longer retain the original shape, however the exported referenced image will be rectangular.  In any case it is impossible to avoid the margin unless you zoom in enough to fill the frame, You can control the colour of the background on export. You could try to export to PNG, then make the solid background transparent in Photoshop. Have not tried this.